How to use autohotkey with Vim?
I´m new to Vim and I want to use autohotkey to make it so that, if I open Vim on PowerShell, the Esc key is Remapped to the CapsLock key so that I can change from Insert to Visual Mode faster.
I tried running this script:
#HotIf WinActive('Title' 'ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass')
#HotIf WinActive('vim')
CapsLock::Esc
#HotIf WinActive
#HotIf WinActive

But it didn't seem to work.

Correction, pressing the <Esc> key in insert mode puts you back in normal mode, not visual mode.

well I have no idea of autohotkey, but a quick google gave me several options one of them is indeed autohotkey https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows#AutoHotkey  it looks like the if structure should end in HotIf not HotIf WinActive but that could both work. So if that is not the issue, I would guess your ifs to not match...
